# Bootstrap tabs overflow issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How to fix bootstrap tab like this

Before in Fiddle:
[image: My Fiddle]

```
<div class="nav-tabs-custom">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active" ><a href="#Tab1" data-toggle="tab">Tab1</a></li>
                <li class="" ><a href="#Tab2" data-toggle="tab">Tab2</a></li>
                <li class="" ><a href="#Tab3" data-toggle="tab">Tab3</a></li>
                <li class="" ><a href="#Tab4" data-toggle="tab">Tab4</a></li>

            </ul>

    </div>
```

to like this:

[image: After]

Comment: show your code or work

Comment: how to add prev and next button to limit tab just like firefox tab?

Comment: http://codepen.io/ehrenglaube/pen/KpvdPb

Comment: that's cool, but i am still newbie... not yet learn angular :(, how about pure javascript or jquery? help me please

Answer (score 0):

Try adding  to your `nav-bar-custom`

```
   display: inline-block;
```

and  for the button you can try with glyphicon

```
<div class="nav-tabs-custom">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active" ><a href="#Tab1" data-toggle="tab">Tab1</a></li>
            <li class="" ><a href="#Tab2" data-toggle="tab">Tab2</a></li>
            <li class="" ><a href="#Tab3" data-toggle="tab">Tab3</a></li>
            <li class="" ><a href="#Tab4" data-toggle="tab">Tab4</a></li>

            <li class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></li>
            <li class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></li>

        </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: how to add prev and next button to limit the tabs like firefox tab?

Comment: I have update the answer. I hope this  could be useful